# Passing a DataSet in to a T-SQL stored procedure as a parameter from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, dataset, profiler

I am attempting to pass a populated dataset from C# to a SQL Server stored procedure parameter, but I'm having trouble.

Here is my C# code:

```
if (tblNoMatch.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    pge.dbconn.ExecuteNonQuery("dbo.MySproc",
                               new SqlParameter("@MyTableParam", tblNoMatch),
                               new SqlParameter("@IsProcessed", "2")
                              );

    pge.dbconn.ShutDown();
}
```

where `tblNoMatch` is type `DataSet`, and populated with a column `ID`. The dataset variable is filled with 40 rows of `ID` values.

Here is my SQL end:

```
IF TYPE_ID(N'MyTable') IS NULL
    CREATE TYPE dbo.MyTable AS TABLE(BatchID INT);
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc] 
    @MyTableParam AS dbo.MyTable READONLY,
    @IsProcessed [smallint] = 0
AS
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MyTableParam) > 0
        --Process Records from Batch 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
        SET [IsProcessed] = ISNULL(@IsProcessed, IsProcessed)
        WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT ID FROM @MyTableParam)
    END
```

When I sniff the throughput with SQL Server Profiler tool, I don't even see `@MyTableParam` getting passed, and on the SQL Server end, it's getting ignored entirely.

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I made this alteration as I know the parameter needs to be of type `Structured`, but this unfortunately did not do the trick for me either:

```
if (tblNoMatch.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var tblParameter = new SqlParameter
                           {
                                ParameterName = "@MyTableParam",
                                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                                Value = tblNoMatch
                           };

    pge.dbconn.ExecuteNonQuery("dbo.MySproc", tblParameter,
                               new SqlParameter("@IsProcessed", "2"));

    pge.dbconn.ShutDown();
}
```

What else am I missing here?

Comment: What is ```pge```?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the TypeName as follows...

```
tblParameter.TypeName = "dbo.MyTable";
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, still does not pass the parameter to my SPROC. It's not even showing up in my profiler hit... Anything else i can try?